# Imputing missing timestamp indices in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a snapshot of a dataframe `df` I'm working with

```
2014-02-01 09:58:03  1.576119   0.0   8.355      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:58:33  1.576119   0.0  13.371      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:59:03  1.576119   0.0  13.833      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
```

With Timestamp indices spaced by 30 seconds. I'm trying to concatenate a number of rows populated by `np.nan` values, while keeping with the pattern of 30 second separated Timestamp indices, i.e. something that would look like

```
2014-02-01 09:58:03  1.576119   0.0   8.355      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:58:33  1.576119   0.0  13.371      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:59:03  1.576119   0.0  13.833      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:59:33       NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN        NaN    NaN
2014-02-01 10:00:03       NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN        NaN    NaN
```

However, when I apply

```
df = pd.concat(df, pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.nan, np.nan])))
```

I'm instead left with

```
2014-02-01 09:58:03  1.576119   0.0   8.355      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:58:33  1.576119   0.0  13.371      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:59:03  1.576119   0.0  13.833      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
0                         NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN        NaN    NaN
1                         NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN        NaN    NaN
```

My question is: **how I can get the timestamp index pattern to continue? Is there something I should specify in the creation of the dataframe to be concatenated, or can I re-index the dataframe shown above?**

---

For a more complete problem statement, I'm working with several time-series dataframes, each of which is hundreds of thousands of rows with the same initial time, varying ending times, and some missing values for each dataframe; I'm trying to get them to match lengths so I can interpolate NaN values by an `np.nanmean()` at that element's index over all dataframes, which I'm doing by stacking the associated numpy arrays for each dataframe -- applying this averaging procedure across the arrays requires them to have the same dimensions, hence I am filling them with NaNs and interpolating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you done concatinating:

Make use of `pd.date_range()` and `index` attribute:

```
df.index=pd.date_range(df.index[0],periods=len(df),freq='30S')
```

output of `df`:

```
2014-02-01 09:58:03  1.576119   0.0   8.355      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:58:33  1.576119   0.0  13.371      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:59:03  1.576119   0.0  13.833      0.0    0.0        1.0    0.0
2014-02-01 09:59:33       NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN        NaN    NaN
2014-02-01 10:00:03       NaN   NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN        NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is the case that you have, say, two `DF`'s - `df_big` and `df_small`.  And the row indices in `df_small` match the beginning row indices of `df_big` you could:

Add the `NaN` rows as you describe above so that the number of rows in `df_small` matches the number of rows in `df_big`.

Then copy the index from `df_big` to `df_small`.

```
df_small.index = df_big.index
```

---

**A different idea:**

You could use the time delta between the last two rows to generate new index entries.

Set number of entries to add.

```
rows_to_add = 2
```

Create a new and extended index based on your original `DF` - before you add the `NaN` rows:

```
ext_index = list(df.index) + \
    [df.index[-1] + (df.index[-1] - df.index[-2]) * x for x in range(1,rows_to_add+1)]

[Timestamp('2014-02-01 09:58:03'),
 Timestamp('2014-02-01 09:58:33'),
 Timestamp('2014-02-01 09:59:03'),
 Timestamp('2014-02-01 09:59:33'),
 Timestamp('2014-02-01 10:00:03')]
```

Then add your `NaN` rows as in your question. (The same number of rows as the constant `rows_to_add`).

Then set your new index:

```
df.index = ext_index
```

Comment: These are good answers. I'm going to select the other answer as the accepted answer for its combination of simplicity + generalizability to cases in which there are no other dataframe index to copy from, but I like your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea.  (Doesn't directly answer your question but might help).  This would be useful in situations where not all of your missing data is at the end of the frame.

Create a DF with date range in index:

```
df_nan = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range('2014-02-01 09:58:03',periods=5,freq='30S')
)
```

Outer join with your smaller `DF`:

```
df.join(df_nan, how='outer')

2014-02-01 09:58:03  1.576119  0.0   8.355  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2014-02-01 09:58:33  1.576119  0.0  13.371  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2014-02-01 09:59:03  1.576119  0.0  13.833  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
2014-02-01 09:59:33       NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2014-02-01 10:00:03       NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```